# Rounded decimal truncating small values - rounding up

Tags: sql-server, types, decimal, number-formatting

I have, for instance, 1000 tomatoes that costs a total of $4.00.  This would be `0.004` per tomato. My data type is a `decimal (9,2)`.

If I wanted to round that value up to `0.01`, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: how is that possible `0.004` = `0.01` when rounded? isn't it `0.00`?

Comment: What are your rules for the rounding?

Comment: I think they want more of a `Math.Max()` function, the higher of the two values.  They don't want to display anything under one penny.

Comment: @JW One penny is the smallest possible monetary value.

Comment: @RobertHarvey my bad. you're right `:)`

Comment: Are you asking to do this in a programming language or only in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Round(CEILING(0.004 * 100)/100,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  case 
        when cast(4.00/1000 as decimal(9,2)) < 0.01 then 0.01
        else cast(4.00/1000 as decimal(9,2))
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select ceiling(0.004*100)/100
```